# Abbreviated cite with Biblatex's philosophy-modern style

Tags: tables, biblatex, margins, citing

I am writing my master thesis with `classicthesis` and I decided to use Biblatex's philosophy-modern style

```
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,hyperref,square,natbib,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
```

Unfortunately, I need to cite some references inside tables as follows:

[image]

The problem is that this style is too long for a table and the table overflows the short margins of `classicthesis`. There is a way to shorten the description (maybe only first author or something similar)? Or there is a better way to avoid this problem?

Comment: It would be nice to have a minimal (non-)working example.

Comment: You can locally change `maxnames` (as the `natbib` compatibility mode does: [see here](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/master/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-natbib.def#L8)), that might interfere with the `uniquelist` option though and might not work as expected. But really, I would not try and change a label mid-text (even for one appearance) at best it will look weird, at worst it causes unnecessary confusion for the reader. Maybe a line break in the table can help (you can even use automatically breaking ones).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably find an appropriate one among many citation commands provided by biblatex. Search for biblatex manual, this is in chapter 3.7. You'll probably go with `\citeauthor*` or `\footcite`.