# Extra } or forgotten \endgroup when using footcite in table

Tags: tables, footnotes

I have a problem using `footcite` of `bibtex` and `\makesavenoteenv` of `footnote` together.

This is my (not so minimal) MnWE, where I am trying to use `\footcite` inside a `table` floating environment:

```
\documentclass[10pt,
               a4paper,
               twoside,openright,
%              oneside,openany,
               titlepage,
               headinclude,,footinclude,
               BCOR5mm,
               cleardoublepage=empty,
               tablecaptionabove,
               ]{scrreprt}

% Language + Encoding     
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian,english]{babel}

% Typography
%\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{mparhack,fixltx2e,relsize}

% Figures + Tables
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% Units
\usepackage{siunitx}

% Chemistry
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

% Quote
\usepackage[font=small]{quoting}  

% Bibliography
\usepackage[style=philosophy-modern,hyperref,square,natbib,backend=bibtex]{biblatex}                                          
\addbibresource{bibliography/Bibliography.bib}

% Footnotes
\usepackage{footnote}
%\makesavenoteenv{tabular}
%\makesavenoteenv{table}

\usepackage[eulerchapternumbers,
            subfig,
            beramono,
            eulermath,
            pdfspacing,
            listings,
            ]{classicthesis}

\usepackage{arsclassica}

% Graphs
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{l c c c c}
    \toprule
    & $E_b^\text{\ce{O2}}$ (\si{\electronvolt}) & $d_\text{\ce{O}-\ce{O}}$ (\si{\angstrom})& $E_b^\text{\ce{N2}}$ (\si{\electronvolt}) & $d_\text{\ce{N}-\ce{N}}$ (\si{\angstrom})\\
    \midrule
    GGA & \num{-5.855} & \num{1.215} & \num{-10.138} & \num{1.096} \\
    Exp. \footcite{Wang2008} & \num{-5.12} & \num{1.21} & - & - \\
    GGA\footcite{Stampfl1999} & - & - & \num{-9.867}& \num{1.105}\\
    GGA\footcite{Zoroddu2001} & - & - & \num{-10.558} & \num{1.113}\\
    Exp.\footcite{Stampfl1999} & - & - & \num{-9.9}& \num{1.10}\\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}

    \caption{Comparison of calculated binding energy and bond lengths for \ce{O2} and \ce{N2} with experimental and other theoretical values.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

During the compilation, I get the following error:

```
./Untitled.tex:69: Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<argument> ...@finalstrut \strutbox }\fn@endnote }

l.69    Exp. \footcite{Wang2008} 
                               & \num{-5.12} & \num{1.21} & - & - \\
```

When I comment `\makesavenoteenv` the compilation finishes without errors, but obviosuly the footnotes do not appear (but the footnote number is present in the table).

How can I fix this problem?

---

I don't necessarely need to have the footnotes at the bottom of the page. Something like the following would be great:

[image]

This table has been taken from an article appeard in *Physical Review B*, which is written in LaTeX ([REVTeX](https://journals.aps.org/revtex))

Comment: As far as I can see, this is not a `biblatex` problem, the problem even occurs if I make the `\footcite`s into `\footnote`s. Indeed it seems that `arsclassica` seems to clash with `\makesavenoteenv`.

Comment: @moewe Unfortunately commenting `arsclassica` does not change anything.

Comment: The `footnote` package has been unmaintained for several years. Moreover, trying to footnote a table float is hopeless.

Comment: @egreg I reeally need it in order to solve this issue: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290383/abbreviated-cite-with-biblatexs-philosophy-modern-style Any idea?

Comment: I'd set the references in the caption.

Comment: @egreg I don't like that very much... What about a minipage insite the floating environment?

Comment: If you want footnotes inside floats, put the entire float inside a minipage. Then footnotes will be set directly under the table.

Comment: You can either use the `minipage` solution from [Footnote in table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35615/35864), or choose something that works for you from [Footnotes in tables?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1583/35864). Be aware of [Aberrant footnote numbering behavior with footnoted captions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43778/35864)