# Adding footnote to the table leads to the error: ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup

Tags: tables, footnotes, siunitx, tablenotes, nicematrix

By making tables I am using packages `siunitx`, `nicematrix` and `makecell`. These three packages applied simultaneously seems to be sufficient for solving my problems with tables - like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562752/how-to-make-a-table-with-multirow-rotated-cells). I am using `siunitx` package, not `dcolumn` package, because the last one gives not satisfying placement of numbers.
I met the problem with placing the table note. The note mark has to be placed in the cell of the middle column. While I am using `S`-type column within `NiceTabular` environment I got the error:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
<template> ...z@ plus.5fill\relax \egroup \egroup 
                                                  \begingroup \CT@setup \CT@...
l.23 ...tal & 160\tabularnote{My footnote text.} &
                                                   100,0\\
```

How to solve this problem? It resembles [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290583/extra-or-forgotten-endgroup-when-using-footcite-in-table) (in this topic probably one of @moewe's comments leads to the solution, nevertheless I can't cope with it).
Code:

```
\documentclass[table]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\begin{document}
{\footnotesize
    \begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines,code-before=\rowcolor{gray!50}{1-1}]{
        l
        S[table-format=3,zero-decimal-to-integer,table-space-text-post=\textsuperscript{a}]
        S[table-format=3.1]
    }
        {\thead{Side-heading\\description}} &
        {\thead{First column\\with data\\description}} &
        {\thead{Second column\\with data\\description}}\\
        Good & 120, & 41,5\\
        Bad & 140, & 58,5\\
        Total & 260,\tabularnote{My footnote text.} & 100,0\\
    \end{NiceTabular}
}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I'm the author of `nicematrix`)

In a first answer to this question, I have said that the problem of the OP is a (partial) incompatibility between `nicematrix` and the columns `S` of `siunitx`. I've given a workaround with `\tablenum` of `siunitx`.

Here is another workaround: `siunitx` is not used at all (in the first column). This is really a heavy workaround because you have to do the job of centering by hand will `\hphantom` and `\rlap`. However, by this way, the contents are strictly centered (including the labels of the tabular notes).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}


\protected\def\myfootnote{My table note.}

\begin{document}
{\footnotesize
    \begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines,code-before=\rowcolor{gray!50}{1-1}]{
        l
        c
        S[table-format=3.1,zero-decimal-to-integer]
    }
        {\thead{Side-heading\\description}} &
        {\thead{First column\\with data\\description}} &
        {\thead{Second column\\with data\\description}}\\
        Good  & 120,5\hphantom{\textsuperscript{a}} & 41,5\\
        Bad   & 140\rlap{\tabularnote{My first note}}\hphantom{,5\textsuperscript{a}}  & 58,5\\
        Bad   & 140,5\tabularnote{My second note}  & 58,5\\
        Total & \hphantom{0}60\hphantom{,5\textsuperscript{a}} & 100,0\\
    \end{NiceTabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 8):

(I'm the author of `nicematrix`).

This is a partial incompatibility between `nicematrix` and the columns `S` of `siunitx`.

I will try to find a solution but here is a workaround by using the command `\tablenum` of `siunitx` (which is the 'command version' of the `S` column type).

However, the command `tablenum` seems to delete all the spaces in its argument (and it will delete the spaces in the text of the tabular note). That's why I have put the text of the tabular note in a TeX macro `\myfootnote` (it would be possible to use `\NewDocumentCommand` but I wanted to emphasize the fact that it must be protected).

Moreover, the case of an integer number requires a special treatment...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\footnotesize\bfseries}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker={,}}

\NewDocumentCommand { \mytablenum } { } { \tablenum[table-format=3,zero-decimal-to-integer]}

\protected\def\myfootnote{My table note.}

\begin{document}
{\footnotesize
    \begin{NiceTabular}[hvlines,code-before=\rowcolor{gray!50}{1-1}]{
        l
        c
        S[table-format=3.1]
    }
        {\thead{Side-heading\\description}} &
        {\thead{First column\\with data\\description}} &
        {\thead{Second column\\with data\\description}}\\
        Good  & \mytablenum{120,5{\tabularnote{\myfootnote}}} & 41.5\\
        Bad   & \mytablenum{140,}  & 58.5\\
        Total & \mytablenum{60}\rlap{\tabularnote{Another table note.}} & 100.0\\
    \end{NiceTabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: Thank you for the response. Now I am trying to apply this to the integer number - it is not correct to emphasize that in some process is not engaged the fractional part of person, by adding decimal part to the number (in Polish komma is s decimal separator). Could you give some prompt, how to apply your solution to column with integers, please?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean but I have modified my answer to put a tabular note next to an integer number (it's a workaround...).

Comment: In my table the number of people has to be eg. `721`, not `721.0`. Removing the statement `table-space-text-post=\textsuperscript{a}` leads to wrong horizontal placement: the widest string (according to my guidebooks), which in your response is `120,5a` has to be centered horizontally in the cell. But adding `table-space-text-post=\textsuperscript{a}` gives unwanted space between number and footnotemark.

Comment: In the second column, you don't have tabular notes and, so, you can use the `S` column type. You can use the key `zero-decimal-to-integer` in that column (and you will have `100` instead of  `100,0` in my example). However, this is not possible in the first column...

Comment: If you want the contents of the first column centered (including the lables of the tabular notes), I think that, as of now, you will have to drop `\tablenum` in that column and do the job by hand. I have put a second answer where I do the whole job by hand (it's an awful workaround).

Comment: I wonder if putting `table-space-text-post=\textsuperscript{a}` into `\mytablenum` definition and adjustment by hand `\mytablenum{260}\!\!\!\!\tabularnote{\myfootnote}` ensures horizontal centering of the cell content.

Comment: Yes. It would work but the `\!\!\!\!` is an adjustement 'by hand'...

Comment: I am using this workaround in the subsequent tables, and met necessity to apply `\hspace` on both sides of footnotemark, for instance `\mytablenum{19}{\hspace{-2.8mm}\tabularnote{\myfootnote}\hspace{0.7mm}}`. It is because: 1) decimal separators in a given column must be placed on the same vertical line, 2) column content must be horizontally centered with respect to the most protruding elements. Using `\!` command disturb vertical alignment from the point (1).